# SSIS File System Task Editor closes unexpectedly

Tags: ssis

In a package I am developing, I am having an issue using a variable for the destination connection in the File System Task.  I have done the following:

- I dragged a new File System Task to the design surface.
- I changed the IsDesinationPathVariable parameter to true

When I use the drop down arrow to select a variable, the editor closes.  The same thing happens when I try and paste the variable name.

I have highlighted the drop down that causes the editor to close below:
[image]

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 to develop the package, build 11.0.50727.1. The SQL Server Integration Services Designer is version 11.0.3436.0.

Comment: I have a project parameter that has it's value set to Sensitive=True.  When I change it to False, then the editor does not close.

Comment: Is the project parameter used as the DestinationVariable or is that just part of the repro?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue. I have managed to get around it by manually entering the variable I'm using in the "Destination" property on the Properties window for the File System Task.  For instance, "User::DestFileName".